# Aapt is not working correctly - cannot generate R IDs on fresh project

Tags: android, aapt

I am running headless Ubuntu Server, with Jenkins, for Android builds, mostly for testing, several physical devices are connected all the time.

Week ago it started to behave wierd, it was impossible to have sucesful build on this machine. At first I thought it might be something with code, then pom.xml files.

Maven projects are throwing the same error (132):

```
[INFO] Illegal instruction (core dumped)
[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
...
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/sks/Wieliczka/app && /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/aapt package -m -J /var/lib/jenkins/sks/Wieliczka/app/target/generated-sources/r -M /var/lib/jenkins/sks/Wieliczka/app/AndroidManifest.xml -S /var/lib/jenkins/sks/Wieliczka/app/res -S /var/lib/jenkins/sks/Wieliczka/app/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res --auto-add-overlay -A /var/lib/jenkins/sks/Wieliczka/app/assets -I /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar, Result = 132
```

I created fresh project with "android create project" command, then I tried to build it with Ant, same error in result

```
[aapt] Generating resource IDs...

BUILD FAILED
/opt/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:690: null returned: 132
```

Machine runs on 32bit processor and it is pretty old, I believe ~7 years old

Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Java version

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Android SDK is up to date, actually I already redownloaded and reinstalled it twice :-/

Comment: Bug in Latest Release just Clean Up the Project and Things go Well.

Comment: But this is pointless, problems occurs not only in old projects but in freash ones as well. Besides this machine is headless, it has no GUI at all.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue right now. =/   (Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, Apache Maven 3.0.4, Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc., build-tools/18.0.1) ... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58663

Comment: @duskstriker yeah, the problem was with Build-tools 18.0.1, for some reason they don't work with 32bit procesor computer, we switchet to 64bit machine and everyting is OK, but since then Google relased Build-tools 18.1, so the problem may be already solved

Comment: @outlying You should post that as an answer and accept it to get this question out of the unanswered list.